# How display errors in html without refreshing the form

Tags: php, html

this is the php code im using and want these errors(Echos) to be displayed in the html form without refreshing it after the submit button is clicked
.
THANK YOU

```
<?php
include 'index.php';


 ........

if (mysqli_num_rows($num_u) > 0  && mysqli_num_rows($num_e) > 0 ) {
        echo  "User Already Excist";    
}   


<html>
```

Comment: You'll need to AJAX your form contents to the PHP file, then handle them in JavaScript.

Comment: As @MCMXCII said, you will need AJAX.  How is your JQuery?  Jquery makes Ajax easier

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, changing page content without refreshing a page isn't possible in PHP. PHP runs when the page loads but once it's finished processing the only way to start the same or a new script is to make a new request. You'll have to use Javascript to execute an ajax request to populate the error.

Comment: is there anything i can do with sessions to solve that,

Comment: @ImankaPriyasadAmarakoon — No. Read the first sentence of this answer again.

Answer (score -1):

**You need to use JQuery's ajax methods.**

They can get data from the server and update your dom on the fly without a page reload.

This is pretty straightforward using Get or Post

JQuery also has some other [ajax](https://www.formget.com/jquery-login-form/) methods which may be useful as well.

You can check this *[Create Login Form Using jQuery](https://www.formget.com/jquery-login-form/)* blog for more details, I hope it's help to you

Comment: can sessions do something?

Comment: @ImankaPriyasadAmarakoon — No, Without page refresh, you can not set session. 
You can use Ajax request and set the value in the session but it does not make sense then you need to be handled with the Javascript and jQuery